# Why mongoose independently sends a 404 response?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In General, there is a method which updates the user and sends the object with the updated data:

```js
exports.update = function(req, res) {
  if (req.diffUser) {
    User.update({
      _id: req.user.id
    }, req.diffUser, function(err) {
      if (err) {
        throw err;
      } else {
        User.findById(req.user.id, '-password -salt -email', function(err, user) {
          if (err) {
            throw err;
          }
          if (!user) {
            res.status(400).json({
              type: 'Error',
              message: 'User not found =/...hmm'
            });
          } else {
            res.json(user);
          }
        });
      }
    });
  } else {
    req.status(400).json({
      type: 'Error',
      message: 'No difference'
    });
  }
};
```

Now, for some not driven me reason, row 3 (User.update) sends a 404 response to the client, then the code runs quietly and in the end drops out with the error "Can't set headers after they are sent. Why it might happen?

Comment: "Can't set headers after they are sent" indicates that something is writing/has written the response to the client already. So somewhere you have a piece of code that is already responding to the url this middleware is hosted at. I can't see a 404 or you calling next here so I'm going to assume it's another piece of middleware causing this.

Comment: Yes . The response comes on line 3...and I don't know why

Comment: Are you sure your User.update command works okay? I think it should be like User.update({_id : req.user.id}, {$set: {_id: req.diffUser}}, function(err){... It can be totally unrelated but check the documentation; http://mongoosejs.com/docs/2.7.x/docs/updating-documents.html